# How do I generate a unique token (for e-mail verification)?

Tags: random, go

I want to implement a system that after user signs up, user will receive an email includes a link to verify this email is for that user.

The way I generate the token for verifying the email is like this:

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
)

func generateToken() (string, error) {
    b := make([]byte, 35)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b), nil
}
```

But what I want to ask is if this method is OK? How to make all the token generated by this method is unique ?

What is the normal way to implement this system ?

Please give me some ideas and tell me if this method of generating token is good.

Thanks.

Comment: 2^280 possible values (that number of 85 digits long in base 10) is going be unique. I would just adjust the length of b so you don't need padding on every base64 string.

Answer (score 5):

Check out https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/uuid#NewRandom.

And you may want to consider storing this in a database with the email address and perhaps an expiry date / time so that the verification doesn't stay there forever. You may only want to allow people to verify within 24 hours, or 7 days and so on. Have another job that periodically cleans expired and non-verified emails.

Comment: code.google.com was retired a year ago, and will be taken offline this month.

Comment: Yes, there is one field in my database to store the token. But the thing I can't understand is that almost every website takes the form like : htttp://address/token . And in the URL, there is no information to denote this token is for which user record, so obviously the token can not be the same, it need to be unique.

Comment: But after I checkout the link you provided above, it seems UUID is enough to implement this functionality. It seems the probability of collision is almost impossible.

Comment: `Have another job that periodically cleans expired and non-verified emails.` You can avoid this if you could verify expiry at the time of email verification. save a verification_start_date, to check expiry.

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

- No, the method as presented won't guarantee them to be unique.
- You don't need to have *all* your tokens to be unique.

To expand on these points…

You're dealing with *a set of outstanding* verification requests.
That is:

1. A request is made by the user;
2. You generate a unique verification token and *store* it into some presistent database.  This is needed in order for verification to work anyway.
3. The user receives your e-mail and clicks that link from it which contain your token.  At this point you remove the information about this pending verificaton request from your persistent storage.

As you can see, at any given time you only have several outstanding verification requests.  Hence this situation has two important properties:

- You only need the tokens of these outstanding requests be different from one another.  It's OK to have a verification token to be the same as that of some past (or future) request.
- Your tokens have to be hard-to-guess (obviously).  I'm sure you already understand that.

So, the approach to generating a new token is as follows:

1. Generate something hard-to-guess.
2. Compare it with the tokens bound to the outstanding/pending verification requests persisted in your storage.

   If you find an outstanding request with the same token, you have a collision so go to step (1) and repeat.

   Otherwise the token is OK so proceed with it and persist the data about this request.
3. Once the request passed verification, remove it from your storage.

Exact algorythm for generating tokens does not matter much.  I'd say an UUID or something looking like SHA-256/512 calculated over some random data is OK.

Comment: A 35-byte (280 bit) token generated from crypto/rand is about as unique as you can get. Your comment "No, the method as presented won't guarantee them to be unique" or "I'd say an UUID or something looking like SHA-256/512 calculated over some random data is OK." would not be any better. There is no need to compare with existing tokens as the chance of collision is infinitesimally small.

Comment: @elithrar, the gist of my answer is that there exist a simple and sensible way to ensure uniqueness no matter what approach to generating of the tokens you use. I may be too low-tech but I don't have a degree in math and so why would I play with thinking about the probability of a collision if I just can avoid it using a simple check? I prefer "reliable" over "neat". ;-)

Comment: What if you have tens of thousands of records? (not absurd for a moderately sized site). You can't check every record: it doesn't scale even to a few thousand. 32-byte tokens are fine.

Comment: If you have random data (which crypto/rand is supplying here), taking an SHA2 value of that only reduces the randomness of your data if you have more than the hash's size. If you have less, you're not adding any randomness, so there's no point.

Comment: It seems the solution provided by @Steven S. is enough to this problem. But still thank you for writing this detailed explanation.